# Evaluating and plotting a function z = f(x,y) with different array size of x and y

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Although it's a notebook question, but I am unable to get it correct, my problem is:

1. I have a function y ranging from 0 to 5.3 with 130 divisions
2. I have a function z ranging from 0 to 0.3 with 48 divisions
3. I wanted to plot a function v such that:

   v = cos(2* \pi *z)*sin(\pi *y)
   I tried to do with Python using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

y = np.arange(0, 5.3, 0.007692)

z = np.arange(0,0.3,0.021)

v = np.cos(2.0*math.pi*z)*np.sin(math.pi*y)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter( y, z, v,
           linewidths=1, alpha=.7,
           edgecolor='k',
           s = 200,
           c=v)
plt.show()
```

By looking at the problem or at the code itself it's clear that the array size of y and z are different and correspondingly the function "v" could not be evaluated correctly and thus I am getting the following error:

```
 v = np.cos(2.0*math.pi*z)*np.sin(math.pi*y)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (15,) (690,)
```

I am unable to get it fixed, also I tried to make different arrays for y and z and then using two different loops for y and z evaluated the value for function z, but again I could not do it correctly. Could any one please help.

Using useful comment by @tmdavison [https://stackoverflow.com/users/588071/tmdavison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlIW6.png) I used the `np.meshgrid` I got the following contour, which is close to, what I was expecting, but is it possible to get the 3D plot of y,z,v ? The updated code is given as:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

y = np.arange(0, 5.3, 0.007692)

z = np.arange(0,0.3,0.021)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(y, z, sparse=True)

v = np.cos(2.0*math.pi*xx)*np.sin(math.pi*yy)


h = plt.contourf(y,z,v)

plt.colorbar()


plt.show()


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter( y, z, v,
           linewidths=1, alpha=.7,
           edgecolor='k',
           s = 200,
           c=v)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But it is giving me error which says:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: @Sujay Thanks for your prompt reply, in the y and z axes I expect the usual input range from 0-5.3 and 0-0.3 respectively and in the v axes I expect a "Fourier" kind of function that is a combination of sin and cosine function.

Comment: check my answer @user13680518

Comment: @Sujay Thanks a lot for posting the answer, but, it's not correct, since the divisions that your are making for y and z are a single values and thus correspondingly the plot is nothing but signifying a single values for y, z and v, which is not acceptable at all.

Comment: Its still not clear from your question, but I think you want to make a grid of y and z coordinates to evaluate the function over? If so, you might want to look at [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Comment: @tmdavison Many thanks for your reply, yes I think that is very close to what I was expecting, infact using the `meshgrid` I obtained the contour plot, that's what I was looking for. In addition to that I was expecting a 3D plot of (y,z,v). Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? In older versions I think you needed something like `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D` to allow 3D axes to work

Comment: @tmdavison I guess the version is not an issue, since I am able to plot the 3D graph for some other functions. Meanwhile I am using matplotlib: 3.2.1

Comment: not sure then, sorry. If you try running the example here does it work? https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html

Comment: @tmdavison Thanks a lot, I am very clearly almost at the solution, this will work for me. Thanks again.